# Server for Parallel Programming

Tags: server, performance

I have some parallelized codes. The codes on my machine Intel Xeon CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.5GHz, reduce from 9 hours when non parallelized to 1.37 hours when parallelized. This is a huge gain from a 4 cores dual thread machine.

Now I am looking to buy a server with many many cores, that I can use almost straight from the box (without having to change the way my codes are written). There seems to be a tradeoff between core GHz and number of cores.

I do not really have a budget but I am assuming one can look to things between 1.000gbp - 6.000gbp.

What is the best price to value I can get?

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could revert the close ... but there is actually no way to rephrase my question. It is a simple hardware recomendation question.

Comment: I dont understand why this question was closed, it is clear and understandable, not at all off topic - OP is asking for a hardware recommendation. Anyways, I would recommend you getting a precision t5600 used, maybe off eBay for around $700 with two Xeon e5-2670s or maybe even higher if you think necessary, i think that will definitely be satisfactory, even though its a little lower clockspeed, no more than that is needed for most kinds of programming but it would double your current cores and threads which i definitely think is an important aspect for your need